# OpenLayers 3 - Modify Feature - Delete vertex on keypress

Tags: openlayers, events

I'm trying to create functionality in OpenLayers 3 that allows me to delete a vertex from a feature that is currently selected using the modify interaction.

I've managed to see that there is a 'deleteCondition' parameter set on the modify interaction when it is created, and that this needs to return an ol.events.condition object. At present I can see from this example (http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html) that is it possible to delete a vertex by pressing SHIFT and mouse click at the same time, however this then creates a new point which seems counter-intuitive to me. If you are deleting a vertex why would you want to create a new vertex in exactly the same place? I may have missed something here though.

So the question is how can I use these ol.events.condition objects to make it so that if the user clicks a specific key on the keyboard the highlighted vertex is deleted?

My initial thoughts were to have something like this:

```
var modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: selectInteraction.getFeatures(),
    deleteCondition: function(event) {  

        var key = event.originalEvent.keycode || event.originalEvent.charCode;
        if(key == 46) {
            return  ol.events.condition.always(event);
        } else {
            return ol.events.condition.never(event);
        }
    }
});
```

But this produces some very strange results...

Comment: use shift +mouse click delete vertices in the official example.

Comment: I notice that the behaviour has changed between v3.4.x and v3.5.x.  Previously it would just delete the vertex and ignore the draw interaction (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html).  If you disable the draw interaction then it works, but adding a condition to the draw interaction to try and counter the behaviour didn't work for me http://jsfiddle.net/8d3ygyqt/

Comment: Ah yes you are right, the version 3.4.x seems to work how I would envisage it. Perhaps it is a bug in 3.5.x then?

Comment: I'd say so.  There is nothing obvious in the release notes to indicate this change is intentional (https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.5.0), and I've at least thought adding a condition in the draw interaction (like in my demo above) should work.  https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/new (I can raise it if you like?)

Comment: Yes ok if you could raise it that would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with `freehandCondition` in `Draw` interaction, which is `ShiftKeyOnly` by default. When I changed it to `ol.events.condition.never` I can delete vertex without creating new feature. This solution deactivates freehand drawing.
Example:

```
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
features:features,
type: ('Polygon'),
freehandCondition: function(event){
return ol.events.condition.never(event);
}
```